# Prop watch triggered without change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my component, I have a prop X that I assign to a data Y on created hook, so I can mutate Y peacefully. **Both are Arrays.**

In the meantime, I put a watch on X so I can update Y if the prop changes.

Wierdly though, my watch statement is triggered everytime I use methods like Y.sort()

Looks like this (very simplified):

```js
props: {
    X: Array
},
data: function() {
    return {
        Y: []
    }
},
methods: {
    someFunc() {
        this.Y.sort() // Triggers X's watch
    }
},
watch: {
    X (newVal) {
        this.Y = newVal;
    }
},
created: function() {
    this.Y = this.X;
}
```

Why ?

I already looked at my app from all point of views. There's nothing in the template nor in other methods that would update the prop from the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `this.Y = this.X;` you're referencing `X` by `Y` and any change that affects `Y` will affect also `X`, so to avoid this situation use one of the following solutions :

```
 this.Y = this.X.slice();
```

or

```
Object.assign(this.Y,this.X)
```

JS example :

```js
let a = [44, 23, 16, 5, 52, 36]
console.log(a) //print the original a
let b = a;

b.sort((c, d) => {
  return c - d
});

console.log(a) //a is sorted however we do not call a.sort(...) method
```

Answer (score 1):

All array functions do not mutate the original array.

Except `sort` ;)

And because sort changes the position of items in your array the watcher is triggered.

Comment: Well then, that explains a lot. Thanks for the insight !